# How to change the color of Powerline Glyphs in Jetbrains product

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm here to ask how can I change the front text color of powerline glyph as figure below.

[image]

Like you see, my text is pink but I HATE pink.

So, I can change the pink to black by:

> Setting -> Editor -> Console Color -> Chang Magenta color value from pink to black.

> the value I changed: B309B3 to 262323

But this way doesn't look really good because I changed the value of Magenta instead of setting the color to black.

[image]

How can I actually change the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted this question at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4406999150482-How-to-customize-the-console-color- and the answer is Jetbrains doesn't have this feature yet.